# Adding a new supervisor node to apache storm giving me trouble

Tags: java, linux, apache-storm

I have a 3 node storm cluster (one nimbus, 2 supervisors) and am trying to add another supervisor.  The new supervisor is working locally and has the same config file as the two other supervisors but for some reason whenever I run `$ storm supervisor` it only runs for ~20 seconds then stops.  It's having trouble connecting to the preexisting cluster.  In closing, my question is... how do i connect a supervisor to a preexisting cluster??  Thanks.

Comment: In your **storm.yaml** check if enough number of slots are present. That is if all the slots are full then you will not be able to start a new supervisor. And if this is not the case the check in supervisor log files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue.  I stupidly forgot a single quotation mark.  My file looked like

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - 192.168.2.106"
```

rather than how it should look, which is:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "192.168.2.106"
```